# How to make a video or audio stream

Tags: video, stream, video-streaming

I'm using wirecast to stream video with edition, because is the best I have found.
Anyway I don't have any idea how to stream into my website, I mean like livestream or Ustream how I can stream into a file in my website, I know there are several way like rtmp, html, mms, ftp,.. So what I have to do?

I don't know if I can use this url: rtmp://website-ip:8080/live ?

And when I click to save, it create the live binder?

Sorry I'm kind of lost in this topic, and I haven't found any useful info in internet.

[image: Here is the default optionsin wirecast]

Comment: you need a webpage with a flash player, maybe look for a free one like JWPlayer

Answer (score 1):

You don't "stream" to a file; if you want a "live" streaming (i.e. you're recording at the same time that the video is being broadcast to your viewers) you must run a media server that can handle the rtmp protocol. The server will be running on your web host and configured so that requests to the specified address will be served by the media server which will be connected to your live recording equipments. Setting up such server and equipments is quite complicated, and therefore it's usually easiest to use a third party provider like Justin.tv or Ustream.

On the other hand, if you only need to serve pre-recorded videos, then any regular HTTP server that can serve files will do (i.e. any web server). You will need to use a web video player, perhaps Flash-based or HTML5 video based, like JWPlayer or Video.js and point them to the video file.